# Spring 404 failed routing?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have 2 projects:

1. The imported project from spring starting guides
2. Another project which has the same directory structure and the same code

The first one works but the second one gives me a 404 error.

[image]

I have print screened the directory structure for both of them.
Here is the PostController.java code:

```
   package Post;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

    @Controller
    public class PostController {

        @RequestMapping("/post")
        public String index(Model model)
        {
            System.out.println("Template's fault");
            return "index_posts";
        }


    }
```

Here is the GreetingController.java code:

```
    package hello;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class GreetingController
{
    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public static String index(@RequestParam(value="n1",required=false,defaultValue="1")String n1,@RequestParam(value="n2",required=false,defaultValue="2")String n2,Model mod)
    {
        MathApp mathapp = new MathApp(n1,n2);
        int result = mathapp.addNumbers();
        mod.addAttribute("result", result);
        return "greeting";
    }

}
```

Here is the code that both Application.java files share ( exception being the package):

```
    package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The blog when run gives a 404 error while the gs-serving-web-content-inital when run works like a charm. The MathApp in GreetingController is simply a model and does not affect the app. The pom.xml is quite the same exception being that mysql dependencies are loaded into the blog app.

Thank you

--EDIT--

I'm trying to access `http://localhost:8080/post`
The app does deploy succesfully

Comment: Is blog app deployed successfully? What's the context root on blog app? What URL are you trying to open on browser? What does blog app log, when spring ties blog controller to an URL during deploy?

Comment: @t0mppa check edits. What does the blog app log? Where can I check that?

Comment: Sorry, too busy watching olympics of late. How are you deploying your app? If following the tutorial, then the terminal window is where the application server (Tomcat) logs, just copy the text from there into your question.